# How to get rid of white space on left and right of div?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I want to get rid of the white space on the left and right of the darkgray div. How can I achieve this? What I googled said to just get add padding: 0px; and margin: 0px; but that didn't work. Any ideas?

```css
/*Start of header styling*/

#header {
  background-color: RGB(57, 89, 100);
  Height: 75px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
/*End of header styling*/

body {
  display: block;
}
#subHead {
  background-color: RGB(39, 39, 39);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 350px;
}
/*Start of footer styling*/

/*End of footer styling*/
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>&zwj;</h1>
</div>

<div id="subHead">
  <h1>&zwj;</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Add 'padding: 0; margin: 0;' to the body selector. You should also remove the 'display: block;'.  That's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your CSS by adding

```
html, 
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Usually a CSS reset of such default styles is applied to the document so you can start with a clean slate. [Here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is some great info on the subject of resetting your CSS stylesheets.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  background-color: RGB(57, 89, 100);
  Height: 75px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#subHead {
  background-color: RGB(39, 39, 39);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>&zwj;</h1>
</div>

<div id="subHead">
  <h1>&zwj;</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0` to your `body`rule

Answer (score 0):

The subhead div is not positioned absolutely, so it is being confined by the margin of the body.

One solution is to remove the margin from the body

```
body{
margin:0px;
}
```

Another solution is to also position the sub-div absolutely

```
#subhead{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
left:0px;
}
```

You can add `top:75px;` to position it below the top div.