# Fix footer sticked to the bottom shifted to the right

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to create an HTML page with a footer sticking to the bottom, independently from the size of the browser window. I created the following HTML file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Home </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Home </h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
            aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
            culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <footer id="footer">
            Foo Bar Baz
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my stylesheet is:

```css
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

I used the properties `position` and `bottom` following several guides.

I get the footer at the expected vertical position, but it is shifted horizontally to the right, whatever the window width is. For example: [full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFPqK.png), [medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpKkf.png), [small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBWvk.png).

Where is the error? And how can I fix it?

Comment: where is your problem the footer is at bottom vertically

Comment: @Philo Yes, vertically it is where I need it to, but horizontally there is an undesired margin on the left and the footer is larger than the window (it can be seen because of the scrollbar).

Comment: _"Where is the error?"_ - in 100% width plus 10px padding on each side, resulting in _more_ than 100%. _"And how can I fix it?"_ - go read up on the basics of the _box model_, and discover the `box-sizing` property. (Although in this special case here, I would just leave out the `width` completely, and instead specify `left` and `right`.)

Comment: @CBroe Ouch! So obvious... thank you very much (HTML noob here)! If you write an answer with this, I'll be very glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, if you don't want to show `right` and `left` border of the footer then you can only use `left:0px;` with your footer `CSS`.
i.e.

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    left: 0px;
}
```

And also if you want to show `right` and `left` borders of footer then decrease the `width` of `footer` and increase value of `left` accordingly. Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. This solves half of the problem: the blank space on the left is gone, but the footer is still larger than the window.

Comment: You can simply decrease the `width` e.g `98%` as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the position property outside of normal (such as absolute or fixed), you must give the property you gave on the vertical axis also on the horizontal. The Width value may not work because you are no longer in a normal flow.
Therefore, using it like this will give the correct result.

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to answer your question, please look at this question.
[How to get rid of white space on left and right of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302798/how-to-get-rid-of-white-space-on-left-and-right-of-div)

You have to reset your CSS. You can do this by adding the following to your Code.

```
html, 
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thans for your suggestion. It removes the undesired space the the left, but oddly enough adds space below the footer, basically moving the problem on the other axis.